# Appending to a file in C, reading to an array of struct

Tags: c, append, fwrite, fread

The program asks user to input some records (structures) if necessary and appends them to the existing file or creates a new file if there isn't any, then lists the contents of the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 25

int main() {

  struct studrec {
    char name[20], surname[20], sex, date[12];
  } students[N];
  int i, count = 0;
  char another;

  FILE *fileptr;

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    puts("Press y to continue without adding new records");
    another = getchar();
    if (another == 'y' || another == 'Y') break;
    while ((another = getchar()) != '\n' && another != EOF);
    puts("Input info");

    puts("Name: ");
    if (fgets(students[i].name, sizeof(students[i].name), stdin) == NULL) return 1;
    students[i].name[strlen(students[i].name)-1] = '\0';

    puts("Surname: ");
    if (fgets(students[i].surname, sizeof(students[i].surname), stdin) == NULL) return 1;
    students[i].surname[strlen(students[i].surname)-1] = '\0';

    puts("Sex (m/f): ");
    students[i].sex = getchar();
    while ((another = getchar()) != '\n' && another != EOF);

    puts("Date (dd.mm.yyyy): ");
    if (fgets(students[i].date, sizeof(students[i].date), stdin) == NULL) return 1;
    students[i].date[strlen(students[i].date)-1] = '\0';
    while ((another = getchar()) != '\n' && another != EOF);
   }
   count = i;

   fileptr = fopen("students.txt", "a+");
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++) fwrite(&students, sizeof(students), 1, fileptr);

   rewind(fileptr);
   for (i = 0; (another = fgetc(fileptr)) != EOF && i < N; i++) {
     fseek(fileptr, -1, SEEK_CUR);
     fread(&students, sizeof(students), 1, fileptr);
   }
   fclose(fileptr);

   count = i;
   for (i = 0; i < count; i++) printf("%20s%20s%4c%15s\n", students[i].name, students[i].surname, students[i].sex, students[i].date);

   return 0;
}
```

Everything works normally when writing to a new file.
Output:

```
...input procedure...
Press y to continue without adding new records
y
                Liam               James   m     12.03.1987
               Abbey             Trueman   f     23.07.1943
                Hugo               Brown   m     13.05.1947
```

But then if I run it again and try to append another record to the existing file the program fails:

```
...input procedure...
Press y to continue without adding new records
y
               Nadia          Rachmonoff   f     12.07.1934
                                    O|u                  
                  �u                       �              u
                                           �           E�u
```

It seems that the new record is put in students[0] and all the other elements are erased.
What am I doing wrong? Maybe there's something wrong with the &students pointer. I tried with &students[i] but it returned "segmentation fault" after the first iteration. As I understand the &students address is "automatically" incremented to the next element after every fread/fwrite. If it wasn't so the program would not work correctly on the first run.

Comment: Why do you write *students* to the file *count* times?

Answer (score 3):

You have a few issues with how you deal with the arrays.  First of all, this line:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) fwrite(&students, sizeof(students), 1, fileptr);
```

What you're doing here running a loop, with one pass for each record entered, and **writing the whole array of 25 items to the file** on each pass.  So if 3 records were entered, you write **75**, most of which are garbage or redundant.  What you probably want here is more like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
  fwrite(&students[i], sizeof(students[i]), 1, fileptr);
```

...where the size is the size of *one element* of the array (a single record) and the address is the address of the record you're currently writing rather than the address of the whole array.

You have a similar problem when reading the data later, among others:

```
rewind(fileptr);
for (i = 0; (another = fgetc(fileptr)) != EOF && i < N; i++) {
  fseek(fileptr, -1, SEEK_CUR);
  fread(&students, sizeof(students), 1, fileptr);
}
```

First, the `fread(&students, sizeof(students), 1, fileptr);` should be changed much like the `fwrite()` before, to `fread(&students[i], sizeof(students[i]), 1, fileptr);`.  The reasons are the same: You're reading one record at a time in a loop, so you need to read into *that item* not just to the beginning of the array each time, and the amount of data you read should be the size of *that record* rather than the size of the whole array.

Second, though fixing the above should get it working, you could easily change the loop so that you don't need to read the single `char` in the loop expression to check for EOF.  You should really check for that by checking the return from the `fread()` in the loop instead.  Something like:

```
rewind(fileptr);
for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  if (fread(&students[i], sizeof(students[i]), 1, fileptr) != 1)
    break;
}
```

Or better yet, just read `N` items with no loop, and use the return value to tell you how many were read:

```
rewind(fileptr);
i = fread(students, sizeof(students[0]), N, fileptr);
```

Comment: +1 Just curious. What is the motivation to write so lengthy answer?

Comment: @RomanB. Just for added clarity.  The sorts of mistakes the poster made would probably only be made by someone who has difficulty understanding the details, so a terse answer may be inadequate.  I'd rather explain too much than not enough; extra details can be ignored, but missing details just make the answer unhelpful.

Comment: @RomanB. - Why *not* write a lengthy, detailed answer?  I don't understand this sentiment at all.  Dmitri logged on to Stack Overflow to ask and answer questions.  Providing terse answers seems even more pointless than providing detailed answers!

Comment: KevinVermeer Well, it was merely a discussion between him and me. But if you've mixed in I can ask you the same. I do not understand what is the stimulus of highly professional developers to write such answers and even to read this code. But you're not the one. So you're not right person to ask.

Comment: @KevinVermeer Sorry, I've missed @ in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you so much, Dmitri! Don't know why I thought sizeof[students] was the size of a single record. And the adress of the array is not advanced "automatically", of course! Now everything makes sense. Thanks again, Dmitri, aix and user411313!

Answer (score 0):

The following writes **the entire 25-element array** `count` times:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) fwrite(&students, sizeof(students), 1, fileptr);
```

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Compute the correct size occupied by the `count` elements, and write them out with a single `fwrite` call.
2. Write the entries out one a time, using a loop.

The same goes for the loop that tries to read the elements back: each iteration reads **the entire 25-element array**.

Comment: @RomanB.: It was easy after running the code and looking at the output file.

Answer (score 0):

Your writing code is incorrect, try

```
   fwrite(students, sizeof*students, i, fileptr);

   rewind(fileptr);
   for (i = 0; i < N && fread(&students[i], sizeof*students, 1, fileptr); i++);
```